# Prove or disprove - graph cut

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = (V,E)$ be undirected graph, and let $(A, V/A)$ be a cut (A isn't empty), such that $|V/A|>|A| +1$

$\deg^A(v)$ Is the number of neighbors of v in A, and $\deg^{(V/A)}(v)$ Is the number of neighbors of v in V/A.

We also know that for every $v$ in $V/A$   -  $\deg^{(V/A)}(v) \leq \deg^A(v)$.

Prove or disprove - at least $|E|/2$ edges are crossing the cut.

I am almost certain this claim is true, but after 2 days of trying proving it I gave up.
Any Ideas on how to prove\disprove?

thanks.

Comment: We also know that G is connective, could not edit for some reason

Comment: When you write $V/A$ I take it you mean $V\setminus A$, the complement of $A$.  Then I don't understand " for every $v\in V\setminus A, \deg^{V\setminus A}(v)\leq    \deg^A(v)$  Isn't $\deg^A(v)=0$?  Should it say, $\deg^{V\setminus A}(v)\leq    \deg^V(v)$?

Comment: yes, $ degV∖A(v)≤degV(v)$ for every $v$.
thats what i mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false.  Suppose there are $n>4$ elements of $V\setminus A$ each adjacent to all the others, and $3$ elements of $A$, each adjacent to the other two.  Let there be an element $a\in A$ such that every element of $V\setminus A$ is adjacent to $a$, and let there be no other edges in $G$.  Then there are are $\binom{n}{2}+3+n\geq3n+3$ edges in $G$, only $n$ of which cross the cut.